# The formula of ScoreDoc.score. in Lucene

Tags: java, apache, search, solr, lucene

I want to create a research engine using Lucene. From Lucene documentation, I noticed that `ScoreDoc.score` gives the similarity score between the document and query.

**I want to know how the similarity [score](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/ScoreDoc.html#score) is calculated?**

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Similarly score is calculated based on the similarly model being used in the field on which user is doing the query. There are two I am aware of tf-idf and another is BM25.

Both of those uses the documents characterstics  like doc length, word frequency, idf etc. So you could go through this [link](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html) if it helps

Comment: That link doesn't really explain much about how BM25 works - a much better explanation can be found at [BM25 - The Next Generation of Lucene Relevation](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevance/). BM25 is the default similarity in Solr these days.

Comment: @MatsLindhThe page not found

Comment: @AmanTandon I would like to normalize the scores in Lucene, Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Noran Please refer the https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/6.4.0/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocs.java#L41

You can divide the score given by scoring algo (BM25) by the max score returned by the getMaxScore to normalize the score, however could you explain why you want to normalize those values?

Comment: @Noran Here is the corrected link which Mats provided and gives the good explanation of BM25. https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/

Comment: @Noran also adding lucene search package summary having little explaination for class/interfaces if it helps. https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html

Comment: @AmanTandon  Thanks for replying. I want to create a fact checking program. The program determine if the entered text is a fact or not based on the score. But I do not know how can I determine the threshold of the score.

Comment: Could you gave us an example